# Newton-Raphson Root Finding Algorithm

Tags: r, function, for-loop, derivative, root-finding

## Summary of problem

My objective is to create a function called `newton.raphson` to implement the Newton-Raphson root-finding algorithm.

Root Finding Algorithm: x1 = X0 - f(xo)/f'(x0)

I have 2 arguments:

1. `iter` = number of iteration (value = 10^5)
2. `epsilon` = for the tolerance (value = 10^-10)

Can not depend on variables outside of the function

```r
newton.raphson <- function(f, x0, iter=1e5, epsilon=1e-10) {
    x <- x0
    h <- 1e-5
    for (t in 1:iter) {
        drvt <- f((x+h)) - f((x-h)) / (2 * h)
        update <- x - f(x)/ drvt
        if (abs(update) < epsilon) {
            break
        }
        x <- update
    }
    root <- x
    return(root)
}
```

```r
# Define some function to test
f <- function(x) {
    x^2 - 4 * x - 7
}
```

I get the following results:

```
> newton.raphson(f, 0)
[1] 2.000045
> newton.raphson(f, 3)
[1] 5.000024
```

But results should be:

```
-1.316625
5.316625
```

Comment: How can I caculate the derivative

Comment: I need to compute the derivative of f at x in real-time based on f itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivative calculation is a little bit broken - you forgot parenthesis around the difference between `f(x+h)` and `f(x-h)`:

```r
drvt <- ( f(x+h) - f(x-h) ) / (2 * h)
```

Also, you should compare the difference between the old and new root approximation to the tolerance. In order to make things more clear, rename your misleading `update` variable to something like `new.x`. Then, your should check `if (abs(new.x - x) < epsilon)`.